# MPAndroid Chart dissapears after calling invalidate() with new data

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, kotlin-coroutines

In my Weather app, I have a MainFragment which has a button that opens a different fragment (SearchFragment) (via replace), allows a user to select a location and then fetches weather data for that location and loads it in various views including an MPAndroid LineChart. My issue is that whenever I come back from the search fragment, although the new data is fetched for the chart and I'm calling `chart.notifyDataSetChanged()` & `chart.invalidate()` (also tried `chart.postInvalidate()` since it was suggested when working on another thread) after the invalidate() is called the chart simply disappears. What am i missing here?

MainFragment:

```
const val UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY = "UNIT_SYSTEM"
const val LATEST_CURRENT_LOCATION_KEY = "LATEST_CURRENT_LOC"

class MainFragment : Fragment() {

// Lazy inject the view model
private val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModel()
private lateinit var weatherUnitConverter: WeatherUnitConverter

private val TAG = MainFragment::class.java.simpleName

// View declarations
...

// OnClickListener to handle the current weather's "Details" layout expansion/collapse
private val onCurrentWeatherDetailsClicked = View.OnClickListener {
    if (detailsExpandedLayout.visibility == View.GONE) {
        detailsExpandedLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        detailsExpandedArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_black)
    } else {
        detailsExpandedLayout.visibility = View.GONE
        detailsExpandedArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_down_arrow)
    }
}

// OnClickListener to handle place searching using the Places SDK
private val onPlaceSearchInitiated = View.OnClickListener {
    (activity as MainActivity).openSearchPage()
}

// RefreshListener to update the UI when the location settings are changed
private val refreshListener = SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "calling onRefresh()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
}

// OnClickListener to allow navigating from this fragment to the settings one
private val onSettingsButtonClicked: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
    (activity as MainActivity).openSettingsPage()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    // View initializations
    .....
    hourlyChart = view.findViewById(R.id.lc_hourly_forecasts)
    return view
}

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setUpChart()
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        // Shows a lottie animation while the data is being loaded
        //scrollView.visibility = View.GONE
        //lottieAnimView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        bindUIAsync().await()
        // Stops the animation and reveals the layout with the data loaded
        //scrollView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        //lottieAnimView.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}



@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun bindUIAsync() = lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // fetch current weather
        val currentWeather = viewModel.currentWeatherData

    // Observe the current weather live data
    currentWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { currentlyLiveData ->
        if (currentlyLiveData == null) return@Observer

        currentlyLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { currently ->

            setCurrentWeatherDate(currently.time.toDouble())

            // Get the unit system pref's value
            val unitSystem = viewModel.preferences.getString(
                UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY,
                UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
            )

            // set up views dependent on the Unit System pref's value
            when (unitSystem) {
                UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                    setCurrentWeatherTemp(currently.temperature)
                    setUnitSystemImgView(unitSystem)
                }
                UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> {
                    setCurrentWeatherTemp(
                        weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                            currently.temperature
                        )
                    )
                    setUnitSystemImgView(unitSystem)
                }
            }

            setCurrentWeatherSummaryText(currently.summary)
            setCurrentWeatherSummaryIcon(currently.icon)
            setCurrentWeatherPrecipProb(currently.precipProbability)
        })
    })

    // fetch the location
    val weatherLocation = viewModel.weatherLocation
    // Observe the location for changes
    weatherLocation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { locationLiveData ->
        if (locationLiveData == null) return@Observer

        locationLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { location ->
            Log.d(TAG,"location update = $location")
            locationTxtView.text = location.name
        })
    })

    // fetch hourly weather
    val hourlyWeather = viewModel.hourlyWeatherEntries

    // Observe the hourly weather live data
    hourlyWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { hourlyLiveData ->
        if (hourlyLiveData == null) return@Observer

        hourlyLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { hourly ->
            val xAxisLabels = arrayListOf<String>()
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH")
            for (i in hourly.indices) {
                val formattedLabel = sdf.format(Date(hourly[i].time * 1000))
                xAxisLabels.add(formattedLabel)
            }
            setChartAxisLabels(xAxisLabels)
        })
    })

    // fetch weekly weather
    val weeklyWeather = viewModel.weeklyWeatherEntries

    // get the timezone from the prefs
    val tmz = viewModel.preferences.getString(LOCATION_TIMEZONE_KEY, "America/Los_Angeles")!!

    // observe the weekly weather live data
    weeklyWeather.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { weeklyLiveData ->
        if (weeklyLiveData == null) return@Observer

        weeklyLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { weatherEntries ->
            // update the recyclerView with the new data
            (weeklyForecastRCV.adapter as WeeklyWeatherAdapter).updateWeeklyWeatherData(
                weatherEntries, tmz
            )
            for (day in weatherEntries) { //TODO:sp replace this with the full list once the repo issue is fixed
                val zdtNow = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of(tmz))
                val dayZdt = Instant.ofEpochSecond(day.time).atZone(ZoneId.of(tmz))
                val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")
                val formattedNowZtd = zdtNow.format(formatter)
                val formattedDayZtd = dayZdt.format(formatter)
                if (formattedNowZtd == formattedDayZtd) { // find the right week day whose data we want to use for the UI
                    initTodayData(day, tmz)
                }
            }
        })
    })

    // get the hourly chart's computed data
    val hourlyChartLineData = viewModel.hourlyChartData

    // Observe the chart's data
    hourlyChartLineData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { lineData ->
        if(lineData == null) return@Observer

        hourlyChart.data = lineData // Error due to the live data value being of type Unit
    })

    return@async true
}

...

private fun setChartAxisLabels(labels: ArrayList<String>) {
    // Populate the X axis with the hour labels
    hourlyChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
}

/**
 * Sets up the chart with the appropriate
 * customizations.
 */
private fun setUpChart() {
    hourlyChart.apply {
        description.isEnabled = false
        setNoDataText("Data is loading...")

        // enable touch gestures
        setTouchEnabled(true)
        dragDecelerationFrictionCoef = 0.9f

        // enable dragging
        isDragEnabled = true
        isHighlightPerDragEnabled = true
        setDrawGridBackground(false)
        axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
        axisLeft.setDrawLabels(false)
        axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
        xAxis.isEnabled = true

        // disable zoom functionality
        setScaleEnabled(false)
        setPinchZoom(false)
        isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false

        // disable the chart's legend
        legend.isEnabled = false

        // append extra offsets to the chart's auto-calculated ones
        setExtraOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 10f)

        data = LineData()
        data.isHighlightEnabled = false
        setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6f)
        setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.bright_White, null))
    }

    // X Axis setup
    hourlyChart.xAxis.apply {
        position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        textSize = 14f
        setDrawLabels(true)
        setDrawAxisLine(false)
        granularity = 1f // one hour
        spaceMax = 0.2f // add padding start
        spaceMin = 0.2f // add padding end
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.work_sans)
        }
        textColor = resources.getColor(R.color.black, null)
    }

    // Left Y axis setup
    hourlyChart.axisLeft.apply {
        setDrawLabels(false)
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
        isEnabled = false
        isGranularityEnabled = true
        // temperature values range (higher than probable temps in order to scale down the chart)
        axisMinimum = 0f
        axisMaximum = when (getUnitSystemValue()) {
            UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> 50f
            UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> 150f
            else -> 50f
        }
    }

    // Right Y axis setup
   hourlyChart.axisRight.apply {
       setDrawGridLines(false)
       isEnabled = false
   }
}
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
class WeatherViewModel(
private val forecastRepository: ForecastRepository,
private val weatherUnitConverter: WeatherUnitConverter,
context: Context
) : ViewModel() {

private val appContext = context.applicationContext

// Retrieve the sharedPrefs
val preferences:SharedPreferences
    get() = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)

// This will run only when currentWeatherData is called from the View
val currentWeatherData = liveData {
    val task = viewModelScope.async {  forecastRepository.getCurrentWeather() }
    emit(task.await())
}

val hourlyWeatherEntries = liveData {
    val task = viewModelScope.async {  forecastRepository.getHourlyWeather() }
    emit(task.await())
}

val weeklyWeatherEntries = liveData {
    val task = viewModelScope.async {
        val currentDateEpoch = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
        forecastRepository.getWeekDayWeatherList(currentDateEpoch)
    }
    emit(task.await())
}

val weatherLocation = liveData {
    val task = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()
    }
    emit(task.await())
}

val hourlyChartData = liveData {
    val task = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // Build the chart data
        hourlyWeatherEntries.observeForever { hourlyWeatherLiveData ->
            if(hourlyWeatherLiveData == null) return@observeForever

            hourlyWeatherLiveData.observeForever {hourlyWeather ->
                createChartData(hourlyWeather)
            }
        }
    }
    emit(task.await())
}

/**
 * Creates the line chart's data and returns them.
 * @return The line chart's data (x,y) value pairs
 */
private fun createChartData(hourlyWeather: List<HourWeatherEntry>?): LineData {
    if(hourlyWeather == null) return LineData()

    val unitSystemValue = preferences.getString(UNIT_SYSTEM_KEY, "si")!!
    val values = arrayListOf<Entry>()

    for (i in hourlyWeather.indices) { // init data points
        // format the temperature appropriately based on the unit system selected
        val hourTempFormatted = when (unitSystemValue) {
            UnitSystem.SI.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> hourlyWeather[i].temperature
            UnitSystem.US.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) -> weatherUnitConverter.convertToFahrenheit(
                hourlyWeather[i].temperature
            )
            else -> hourlyWeather[i].temperature
        }

        // Create the data point
        values.add(
            Entry(
                i.toFloat(),
                hourTempFormatted.toFloat(),
                appContext.resources.getDrawable(determineSummaryIcon(hourlyWeather[i].icon), null)
            )
        )
    }
    Log.d("MainFragment viewModel", "$values")
    // create a data set and customize it
    val lineDataSet = LineDataSet(values, "")

    val color = appContext.resources.getColor(R.color.black, null)
    val offset = MPPointF.getInstance()
    offset.y = -35f

    lineDataSet.apply {
        valueFormatter = YValueFormatter()
        setDrawValues(true)
        fillDrawable = appContext.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_night_chart, null)
        setDrawFilled(true)
        setDrawIcons(true)
        setCircleColor(color)
        mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
        this.color = color // line color
        iconsOffset = offset
        lineWidth = 3f
        valueTextSize = 9f
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            valueTypeface = appContext.resources.getFont(R.font.work_sans_medium)
        }
    }

    // create a LineData object using our LineDataSet
    val data = LineData(lineDataSet)
    data.apply {
        setValueTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
        setValueTextSize(15f)
    }
    return data
}

private fun determineSummaryIcon(icon: String): Int {
    return when (icon) {
        "clear-day" -> R.drawable.ic_sun
        "clear-night" -> R.drawable.ic_moon
        "rain" -> R.drawable.ic_precipitation
        "snow" -> R.drawable.ic_snowflake
        "sleet" -> R.drawable.ic_sleet
        "wind" -> R.drawable.ic_wind_speed
        "fog" -> R.drawable.ic_fog
        "cloudy" -> R.drawable.ic_cloud_coverage
        "partly-cloudy-day" -> R.drawable.ic_cloudy_day
        "partly-cloudy-night" -> R.drawable.ic_cloudy_night
        "hail" -> R.drawable.ic_hail
        "thunderstorm" -> R.drawable.ic_thunderstorm
        "tornado" -> R.drawable.ic_tornado
        else -> R.drawable.ic_sun
    }
}
```

}

LazyDeferred:

```
fun<T> lazyDeferred(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T) : Lazy<Deferred<T>> {
    return lazy {
        GlobalScope.async {
            block.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}
```

ScopedFragment :

```
abstract class ScopedFragment : Fragment(), CoroutineScope {
private lateinit var job: Job

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    job = Job()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    job.cancel()
    super.onDestroy()
}
}
```

Comment: could you please post the code of the VM?
this issue is  maybe related threading(update ui on background thread) or to lifecycle management. Data can be empty after return.

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR sure, added it along with the LazyDeferred definition

Comment: How does the `ScopedFragment` look?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy just added it to the post :)

Answer (score 2):

Without the entire environment it's really hard for me to help you debug the whole thing but I am happy to provide you with a couple of things that seem a little bit off at a first glance.

First of all I would avoid managing all CoroutinesScopes and lifecycles by yourself and it's easy to get it wrong. So I would rely on what the Android team has already done. Take a quick look [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies), it's really easy to setup and use. The dev experience is great.

Posting `Deferred` on a `LiveData` and awaiting on the view side looks like a code smell…

- What if there's a network error? 
  It would result in an exception or cancellation exception being thrown.
- What if the task was already perform and causes some type of UI consistency problem? These are a couple of edge cases I would not really want to handle.

Just observe a `LiveData` since it is its main purpose: it's a value holder and it's intended to live throught several lifecycle events in the `Fragment`. So once view is recreated the value is ready in the LiveData inside the ViewModel.

Your `lazyDeferred` function is quite smart but in the Android world it's also  dangerous. Those coroutines don't live inside any lifecycle-controlled scope so they have a really high chance to end up being leaked. And trust me, you don't want any coroutines being leaked since they continue their work even after viewmodel and fragment destruction which is something you definetely don't want.

All of these are easily fixable by using the dependency I've mentioned before, which I'll [paste here once more](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies)

Here's a snippet on how you could use those utilities in your ViewModel to ensure the lifecycle of things nor coroutines are causing any issues:

```kotlin
class WeatherViewModel(
    private val forecastRepository: ForecastRepository,
    context: Context
) : ViewModel() {

    private val appContext = context.applicationContext

    // Retrieve the sharedPrefs
    val preferences:SharedPreferences
        get() = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext)

    // This will run only when currentWeatherData is called from the View
    val currentWeatherData = liveData {
        val task = viewModelScope.async { forecastRepository.getCurrentWeather() }
        emit(task.await())
    }

    val hourlyWeatherEntries = liveData {
        val task = viewModelScope.async { forecastRepository.getHourlyWeather() }
        emit(task.await())

    }

    val weeklyWeatherEntries = liveData {
        val task = viewModelScope.async {
            val currentDateEpoch = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay()
            forecastRepository.getWeekDayWeatherList(currentDateEpoch)
        }
        emit(task.await())
    }

    val weatherLocation = liveData {
        val task = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            forecastRepository.getWeatherLocation()
        }
        emit(task.await())
    }

}
```

By using the following approach all network calls are performed in a parallel fashion and they are all tied to the `viewModelScope` without writing a single line of handling the CoroutineScope's life. When the ViewModel dies, so will the scope. when the view gets re-created the routines won't execute twice and values will be ready to read.

Regarding the configuration of the chart: I would highly suggest you configure the chart as soon as you have created the view, since it is highly tied together. Configuration is something you want to do **just once** and may cause visual bugs if some instructions are executed more than once (which I believe it could be happening to you), just saying so because I've had problems with MPAndroid using a Piechart.

More on the chart: All of the logic of constructing the `LineData` would be better off on a background thread and being exposed through a LiveData in the ViewModel side like you would do with all of the other

```kotlin
val property = liveData {
    val deferred = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // Heavy building logic like:
        createChartData()
    }
    emit(deferred.await())
}
```

**Pro Kotlin tip:** Avoid repeating yourself during those long MPAndroid configurations functions.

Instead of:

```kotlin
view.configureThis()
view.configureThat()
view.enabled = true
```

Do:

```kotlin
view.apply {
    configureThis()
    configureThat()
    enabled = true
}
```

I'm sad that I can just give you these hints and being unable to exactly pin-point what your issue is since the bug is heavily related to what is happenning throughout the lifecycle evolution of the runtime but hopefuly this is going to be useful

### Answering your comment

If one of your data-streams (LiveData) is dependent on what another data-stream (another LiveData) is going to emit you are looking for `LiveData.map` and `LiveData.switchMap` operations.

I imagine that `hourlyWeatherEntries` is going to be emitting values from time to time.

In that case you can use `LiveData.switchMap`.

What this does is that everytime the *source* `LiveData` emits a value, you're going to get a callback and you are expected to return a new live data with the new value.

You could arrange something like the following:

```kotlin
val hourlyChartData = hourlyWeatherEntries.switchMap { hourlyWeather ->
    liveData {
        val task = viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            createChartData(hourlyWeather)
        }
        emit(task.await())
    }
}
```

Using this approach has the benefit that it is completely lazy. That means that **NO COMPUTATION** is going to take place **UNLESS** `data` is being actively observed by some `lifecycleOwner`. That just means that no callbacks are being triggered unless `data` is observed in the `Fragment`

### Further explanation on `map` and `switchMap`

Since we need to do some asynchronous computation that we don't know when it's going to be done we can't use `map`. `map` applies a linear transformation between LiveDatas. Check this out:

```kotlin
val liveDataOfNumbers = liveData { // Returns a LiveData<Int>
    viewModelScope.async {
         for(i in 0..10) {
             emit(i)
             delay(1000)
         }
    }
}

val liveDataOfDoubleNumbers = liveDataOfNumbers.map { number -> number * 2}
```

This is really useful when the computation is linear and simple. What is happening behind the hood is that the library is handling observing and emitting values for you by means of a `MediatorLiveData`. What happens here is that whenever `liveDataOfNumbers` emits a value and `liveDataOfDoubleNumbers` is being observed the callback gets applied; so the `liveDataOfDoubleNumbers` is emitting: 0, 2, 4, 6…

The snippet above is equivalent to the following:

```kotlin
val liveDataOfNumbers = liveData { // Returns a LiveData<Int>
    viewModelScope.async {
         for(i in 0..10) {
             emit(i)
             delay(1000)
         }
    }
}

val liveDataOfDoubleNumbers = MediatorLiveData<Int>().apply {
    addSource(liveDataOfNumbers) { newNumber ->
        // Update MediatorLiveData value when liveDataOfNumbers creates a new number
        value = newNumber * 2
    }
}
```

But just using `map` is much much simpler.

Fantastic!!

Now going to your use-case. Your computation is linear but we want to defer that work to a background coroutine. So we can't exactly tell when something is going to end.

For these use-cases they have created the `switchMap` operator. What it does it's just the same as `map` but wraps everything within another `LiveData`. The intermediate LiveData just acts as a container for the response that is going to come from the coroutine.

So what ends up happening is:

1. Your coroutine publishes into `intermediateLiveData`
2. switchMap does something similar to:

```kotlin
return MediatorLiveData().apply {
    // intermediateLiveData is what your callback generates
    addSource(intermediateLiveData) { newValue -> this.value = newValue }
} as LiveData
```

Summing up: 
1. Coroutine passes value to `intermediateLiveData`
2. `intermediateLiveData` passes value to the `hourlyChartData`
3. `hourlyChartData` passes value to the UI

And everything without adding or removing `observeForever`

Since the `liveData {…}` is a builder to help us create asynchronous LiveDatas without dealing with the hassle of instantiating them we can use it so our `switchMap` callback is less verbose.

The function `liveData` returns a live data of type `LiveData<T>`. If your repository call already returns a LiveData it's really simple!

```kotlin
val someLiveData = originalLiveData.switchMap { newValue ->
   someRepositoryCall(newValue).map { returnedRepoValue -> /*your transformation code here*/}
}
```

Comment: This comment is so amazingly insightful and well explained. I'm honestly amazed how well and clearly you can convey the points of all these tips. Thank you so much. I'll apply everything here tomorrow and give it a try :)

Comment: Let me know how it goes and good night. Hopefully the pillow will bring the solution to you :)

Comment: Hi again, i applied everything you said and to be honest my code looks and feels so much nicer by following these practices. Now onto the main point. The live data for the weather works perfectly but as far as the chart values go, i'll need to observe the `hourlyWeatherEntries` inside my viewModel so that when there is data in it, i can calculate the LineData for the chart.  I've updated my post with the code. The thing is that i don't know how to return the result from the inner observeForever blocks to the async coroutine :) Is there a specific thing i should be doing here?

Comment: I've added a small section on how you could use some of the other utilities to perform what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I've checked the section and the documentation but what i don't get is why do all the fields that are using `liveData {}` have a type of `LiveData<LiveData<T>>`? Is there a workaround to this? This forces me to nest observers to get the actual values for my views which i'm guessing isn't ideal? Plus, for the `hourlyChartData` i'll also have to nest observer and the issue i brought up earlier is raised again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216071/discussion-between-some-random-it-boy-and-stelios-papamichail).

Comment: The chat was frozen for some reason. Feel free to send me the repository and I'll gladly review the code

Answer (score 0):

Separate the setupChart and setData logics. Setup chart once out of the observer, inside the observer setData and after that call invalidate().

Comment: I have applied your changes (updated my post) but no luck so far. Now it won't even display the chart at all.

Comment: Ok, let me check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the `invalidate()` part and wherever you are calling your search function before it try `yourlineChart.clear();` or `yourlineChart.clearValues();`. This will clear the previous values of the chart and will form chart with new values. So, `invalidate()` and `chart.notifyDataSetChanged()` won't not be necessary and it should solve your problem.